# Linq: Find elements of 2 list with different values but same index

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have 2 list of points (`List<Point>`) for the coordinates of some label elements. One list for before and one list for after they were moved, so the indexes refer to the same label elements. I want to compare each element with the same index and see which had their points changed.

```
List<int> changedIndexes = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < labelLocationsBefore.Count; i++)
 {
     if (labelLocationsBefore[i].X != labelLocationsAfter[i].X || labelLocationsBefore[i].Y != labelLocationsAfter[i].Y)
     {
        changedIndexes.Add(i);
     }

 }
```

Which is what this loop does. But how can I convert this into a Linq expression and retrieve the changed labels index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) of `Select` method which takes a `Func<T, int, bool>` where the second argument is the *index*:

```
changedIndexes = labelLocationsBefore
   .Select((point,idx) => new { point, idx })
   .Where(p => p.point.X != labelLocationsAfter[p.idx].X || 
               p.point.Y != labelLocationsAfter[p.idx].Y)
   .Select(p => p.idx)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a better answer than Jon's but I prefer this solution as I find it more clean. Possibly the .Zip would make it slower as well?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `Enumerable.Zip` to join the two collections, then `Select` to get the index of each joined pair, then filter appropriately:

```
var changedIndexes = labelLocationsBefore
    .Zip(labelLocationsAfter, (before, after) => before.Equals(after))
    .Select((equal, index) => new { Moved = !equal, Index = index })
    .Where(result => result.Moved)
    .Select(result => result.Index)
    .ToList();
```

This snippet has a few nice properties (it's based on an expression, easy to read, there is no repetition), but it's necessarily more cumbersome and less performant than a straight `for` loop because of the need to produce the "moved?/index" pair for all before/after sets of points -- even for those where simply determining that they have not been moved would be enough to disregard them.